# How to use Rspec + Guard+Glow+Spork on multiple test folder(spec and capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, spork, guard

I am trying to set up Rspec + guard+glow+spork on my ruby on rails testing on mac. They works just fine on my 'spec' directory.

But I have a different folder with separated helper to store capybara test . What I should do to config guard+glow+spork to make them work on two testing folder on one go 'guard start'.

This is my directory structure briefly

-App\

----spec\

------spec_helper.rb

----scenarios\

------scenario_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different groups for both paths...

```
    # in your Guardfile
    group 'acceptance-tests' do
      guard 'rspec', :spec_paths => ['scenarios/'] do
        # ...
      end
    end

    group 'unit-tests' do
      guard 'rspec', :spec_paths => ['spec/models', 'spec/controllers', 'spec/routing'] do
        # ...
      end
    end
```